# What is the solution for Code 243 Error in code sand box

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The problem is that I have tried changing my  versions a several time still I don't know why is it showing a code 243 error from the latest to the oldest i have tried all. It is not working and when i intall expo cli it shows this error. I need to check my output so this step is necessary any alternative way or solution.

The versions from the latest to the oldest i have tried all. It is not working and when i intall expo cli it shows this error.                      My code =   https://codesandbox.io/p/github/2804whitehatJr/PLANET-API/main?workspaceId=4907e9fa-6bc9-4230-b33b-ab6187fbbcfe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/2804whitehatJr/PLANET-API/main?workspaceId=4907e9fa-6bc9-4230-b33b-ab6187fbbcfe                                                                This is my piece of code which shows the error